# Can I start a second activity with an intent received in the first activity without getParcelableExtra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

It is possible to do this:

[image]

But without hardcoding the value "someData", by receiving an Intent in the FirstActivity, then passing that intent with the value received to the other activity "SomeActivity".

Like this:

`String i1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Zorrupia");`

`adb shell am start -n "com.adon.cors/.MainActivity" -e Zorrupia  "ComemeLosPutosCojones"`

Then being able to retrieve this value "ComemeLosPutosCojones" you receive in the FirstActivity and passing the second one.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No, you should define a tag for every data you want to send to another activity, because you may have different data and they should be recognized correctly in destination.